# TypeError: Failed to fetch with input text

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using the JS code below in React to fetch using a username and password.

When I use input type for username as **text** I get 'TypeError: Failed to fetch' but if I switch the type to **email** then fetch works fine.

Why is that? I don't want the input type as email because it prompts me for other checks like the @ symbol when submitting the form.

My JS:

```js
login() {
  const userObject = {
    username: document.getElementById('inputUsername').value || null,
    password: document.getElementById('inputPassword').value || null
  };
  this.connect('someurl.com', userObject);
}

async connect(url, userObject) {
  try {
    let response = await fetch((url), {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(userObject)
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

My HTML input:

```html
<input type="text" id="inputUsername" />
```

Comment: Where did you get that error? also, can you create working example in snippet?

Comment: I log that on the browser, and it works when I use:
`<input type="email" id="inputUsername" />`

Comment: Please create demo for the same.

Answer (score 0):

when you are using React , you must always save the values of inputs in State and in ajax call send the State value

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      userName: null,
      password: null
    }
    this.UserNameChange = this.UserNameChange.bind(this);
    this.PasswordChange = this.PasswordChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  UserNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      userName: event.target.value
    });
  }
  PasswordChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      password: event.target.value
    });
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('UserName: ' + this.state.userName + ' and Password: ' + this.state.password);
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  render() {
    return ( 
    <div>
      <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}>
      <input type = 'text' onChange = {this.UserNameChange} placeholder = 'UserName' / >
      <br/>
      <input type = 'text' onChange = {this.PasswordChange} placeholder = 'Password' / >
      <br/>
      <input type = "submit" value = "Submit"/>
      </form> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' />
```

Comment: That helps, I've changed my code to use state values, however the problem is still there if I use `<input type="text"/>`